# Changing how object appears in interpreter

Tags: interpreter, python

Is there a way to change how an object appears when displayed at the Python interpreter? For example:

```
>>> test = myobject(2)
>>> test
'I am 2'
```

OR

```
>>> test = myobject(2)
>>> test
myobject(2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can provide a definition for the special `__repr__` method:

```
class Test:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a Test"

>>> a = Test()
>>> a
I am a Test
```

In a real example, of course, you would print out some values from object data members.

The `__repr__` method is described in the Python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).